# Extjs issues with Store

Tags: javascript, extjs, load

I have an Ext.Data.Store. And i have a function, that need to invoke one time, when store is loaded. Only one time.
At first i did this:

```
function invokeMe() {
alert("!");
}

actionTemplateStore.on('load', function () {
    invokeMe();
}
```

But one problem isin this solution: 
I really need once invoce "invokeMe"-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
actionTemplateStore.on('load', function () {
    if (!actionTemplateStore.actionInvoked) {
        invokeMe();
        actionTemplateStore.actionInvoked = true;
    }
}
```

**Update**: as Lloyd mentioned, you can also use {single:true} option.

```
actionTemplateStore.on('load', yourFunction, {single:true});
```

Comment: You're adding a property and conditional logic when there is no need. Event listeners support single execution configuration as I've detailed below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function invokeMe() {
alert("!");
}

actionTemplateStore.on('load',function () {
    invokeMe();
},this,{single: true});
```

We pass in `this` for the scope and a config object with `single: true` which causes it to execute only once.

You could also do this:

```
var onLoad = function(store) {
    alert('!');
    store.un('load',onLoad);
}

actionTemplateStore.on('load',onLoad);
```